How can i display an existing Android dialogfragment inside a jetpack compose screen
My current project is migrating to jetpack compose for its entire UI.
however it contains a number of legacy dialog fragments which i would like to reuse while the migration process continues.
is it possible to use androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView to display a androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment?
